# Does Salesforce support OAuth 1.0

Tags: salesforce1-app, oauth2, oauth, isv

Does anyone know if Salesforce supports OAuth 1.0 ?

Our current solution is based on OAuth 1.0 and in the last week we started getting some issue creating such connection.

Any feedback will help, thanks!

**Update**
I am in discussions with SalesForce Dev support for two days now, they do not seem to have any idea why is it not working.

**Update 2**
According to SalesForce dev support, apparently the Summer 2016 release has a new feature called

> Improved Session Security for OAuth 1.0 Token Exchanges

[Link to the release note](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_security_auth_oauth1_flow_changes.htm)

I think it prevents OAuth 1.0 from working properly, I have just asked to disable it

**Update 3**

Apparently this is a SalesForce.com bug, currenly SalesForce R&D is reviewing this issue (it moved there from Tier-3), I think it is safe to say that anyone that is using OAuth 1.0 to authorize external apps can not do it anymore until this issue is solved.

Comment: did you checked the documentation? https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_1_flows.htm

Comment: The doc URL that you attached specifies it is "Available in: All Editions" , is it up to date?

Comment: Do you want to add Update 2 and 3 as an answer to your own question as it looks like you do have the answer there?

Comment: Hi Dave, well I rather get the review results from SalesForce R&D and then report it fully to this community. I think this post is extremely relevant to any partner who uses OAuth 1.0, I would like to contribute any information I can... When I get review results I will post it as an answer, sounds okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a SalesForce.com bug, currenly SalesForce R&D is reviewing this issue (it moved there from Tier-3), I think it is safe to say that anyone that is using OAuth 1.0 to authorize external apps can not do it anymore until this issue is solved.

(We moved our code to use OAuth 2.0).

**Update**

SalesForce R&D sent me this reply (I guess they owe me a t-shirt :)

> This is just to inform you that R&D has identified this as a known
>   issue has been logged internally on P1(highest priority) basis.